# Get parent method parameter values in nested called method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection

I want to access the parameter of calling method in called method.

```
public class parent 
{
    public void childCall(string childName)
    {
        var childObj = new child();
        //calling child class method
        childObj.logChild();
    }
}

public class child 
{
    public void logChild() 
    {
        // Here i want to use reflection and fetch method parameter,
        // which was passed in this current method call
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: So in `logChild`, you want to access the `childName` argument that was passed into `childCall`?

Comment: Short answer: Not possible, Pass it as a parameter to `logChild` method

Answer (score 3):

Reading caller's parameters is a no-no in .NET - it would be a security hole if called function could access parameters that were not passed to it. Caller must be willing to give its parameters, which means that it needs to comply with certain design.

Possible design would be to accept anything in the child object:

```
public class Child
{
    public void logChild(params object[] parameters)
    {
        foreach (object value in parameters)
        {
            Type type = typeof(object);
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(value, null))
                type = value.GetType();
            // now do something with (type, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just add a parameter to `logChild()` and pass in the value that you need:

```
public class parent 
{
    public void childCall(string childName) 
    {
        var childObj = new child();
        childObj.logChild(childName);
    }
}

public class child 
{
    public void logChild(string childName) 
    {
        //Do something with childName
    }
}
```